# Subfile Compilation with RevTex

Tags: revtex, subfiles

I use `subfiles` package with `RevTex4-1`, and the main file works fine. But when I compile the subfile, I got

```
\bibdata{app-miNotes}
No file app-mi.bbl.
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
\citation{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="08",editor="1",pages="0",title="",year="1"}
\citation{apsrev41Control}
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{0}{}{}{}}
(./app-mi.aux

./app-mi.aux:1: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \
   relax
```

and

```
warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on app-mi.log.
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'app-mi.bbl'
 No file app-mi.bbl.
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  lualatex: Command for 'lualatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'app-mi.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
=== TeX engine is 'LuaTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

What's wrong?

My subfile looks like this

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{section title\label{appendix:mi}}
some texts.
\end{document}
```

and main file (as requested)

```
\documentclass[preprint,aps,prd,showpacs,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib,tightenlines,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\graphicspath{{../figs/}{../../figs/}}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{name}
\email{et@et}
\affiliation{inst}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\keywords{} 
\maketitle 
\subfile{./subfolder/app-mi}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{../filename.bib}{}
\end{document}
```

also I use lualatex but other compilers (tested pdflatex and xelatex) gives the same error.

I don't know if it has anything to do with `RevTex` but I'll use the tag anyway.

Comment: I still can't compile my subfile `app-mi.tex`. Could you tell me how you compile it?

Comment: Not yet. But it definitely has to do with `revtex4-1`. Using a standard class works fine. What is puzzling me is that I do get an error, but a _different_ one.

Comment: what did you got?