# Subfiles failing with custom class

Tags: compiling, document-classes, subfiles, compilation-error

I'm writing a document using the [AASTeX template](https://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex.html), and would like to use the `subfiles` package to manage the sections.

I'm following the ShareLatex example available [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects), and have modified it to use the `aastex61` `documentclass`.

Here's a minimal working example:

Main file:

```
%main.tex
\documentclass[aip,twocolumn,jmp.asmsmath,asmssymb,reprint]{aastex61}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Subfile Example}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subfile{introduction}
\end{document}
```

Subfile:

```
%introduction.tex
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

The main file compiles correctly, but this fails in ShareLatex with

```
Missing \begin{document}
```

In `pdflatex` I get

```
! I can't find file `introduction.aux'.
<to be read again> 
               \relax 
l.13 \end{document}
```

This is unfortunate because I'd like to use `subfiles` for this project. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430003/subfile-compilation-with-revtex (aastex61 loads revtex4-1)

Comment: Imho it won't work with this class, not without lots of changes. revtex4-1 changes the output routine and \enddocument.

Comment: Please keep the bounty; you can make better use of the reputation points than I, since there are some useful privileges tied to the first couple of points. I would appreciate it, though, if at some point you could mark my answer as the one that works for you (green check-mark), in order to signal to me and future visitors that my answer indeed solves the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This problem is resolved in version 1.2 (dated 2018/07/31) of the package, now [available from CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles). If your LaTeX system does not provide an integrated update mechanism, download the files [subfiles.dtx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.dtx) and [subfiles.ins](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.ins). The command

```
pdflatex subfiles.ins
```

generates the files `subfiles.cls` and `subfiles.sty`. Put them somewhere in the search path of TeX such that they are found before any older versions; putting them into the same folder as the LaTeX documents using them should work in any case. The command

```
pdflatex subfiles.dtx
```

will generate the documentation `subfiles.pdf`.

*Background of the problem:* Version 1.1 of the `subfiles` package (dated 2012/05/23) saves the contents of the `\document` command and sets it to `\comment` *before* loading the class and the preamble of the main file. Classes like `revtex` and `aastex` modify the `\document` command, which in this case means that the `\comment` command is modified instead and at `\begin{document}` of the sub-file the original LaTeX version is used instead of the one modified by the class. Both effects will cause all sorts of errors.

Version 1.2 postpones the redefinition of `\document` and works also with 
`revtex` and `aastex`.